# Unable to locate package oracle-java8-installer

Tags: java, debian, debian-jessie

I'm simply trying to install the oracle-java8-installer package in order to install JAVA 8 on my debian server.

No idea why, I get the following output:

```
root@vps:~# sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package oracle-java8-installer
```

Any idea what could have gone wrong?

Comment: Di you adds the repository that contains oracle-java8-installer ?

Answer (score 0):

`oracle-java8-installer` isn't available on debian but you can build the `.deb` package as follows :

> - downloading one of the java binary archive
> - invoking `make-jpkg` to build a Debian package from the downloaded
>     archive
> - installing the generated package

[Detailed instructions on debian wiki : Java Package](https://wiki.debian.org/JavaPackage)